# C program exits without any prompt

Tags: c

The following code should accept input from the user- an array of size *USERDEFINED* and then print it. Following that, it should wait for an input from the user to exit the program, which is defined in the function `waitUntill`. But it does not work as intended. It just prints "PRESS ENTER TO EXIT" and exits without accepting any input. What am I doing wrong here ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void waitUntill();

int main()
{
  int arrSize = 0;
  int array[arrSize];

  printf("\nWhat size of array do you want: ");
  scanf("%d", &arrSize);

  printf("\nEnter %d numbers: ", arrSize);
  for(int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++)
  {
    scanf("%d", &array[i]);
  }
  printf("\nYour array is:\t");
  for(int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++)
  {
    printf("[%d]", array[i]);
  }
  waitUntill();
  return 0;
}

void waitUntill()
{
  printf("\n\nPRESS ENTER TO EXIT !!!\n");
  while(1)
  {
    if (getchar())
      break;
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Think about the order in which you do things! When you define the array `array`, what is the value of `arrSize`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `getchar()` catches the last `\n`, of the previous `string`, you can use it twice:

```
void waitUntill()
{
    printf("\n\nPRESS ENTER TO EXIT !!!\n");
    while(1)
    {
        if (getchar() && getchar())
            break;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

I don't know why you need that infinite cicle, if it's just to catch a random inserted `char` your function can be simpler:

```
void waitUntill()
{
    printf("\n\nPRESS ENTER TO EXIT !!!\n");
    getchar();
    getchar();
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate the array **after** you read its size;

```
void waitUntill();

int main()
{
  int arrSize = 0;
  int *array;

  printf("\nWhat size of array do you want: ");
  scanf("%d", &arrSize);

  array = malloc(arrSize * sizeof(*array));
  if(array)
  {
    ....
    waitUntill();
    free(array);
  }
  return 0;
}

void waitUntill()
{
  printf("\n\nPRESS ENTER TO EXIT !!!\n");
  while(1)
  {
    if (getchar())
      break;
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: @AdrianMole btw, "if one is going to change the type, one must not be lazy and check the memory allocation", I believe it was Confucius who said it... or me... don't quite remember...

Comment: @anastaciu But "if the type changes and no one is watching..." (Confucius) ‎

Answer (score 1):

```
void waitUntill()
{
  printf("\n\nPRESS ENTER TO EXIT !!!\n");
  while(1)
  {
    fflush(stdin);
    if (getchar())
      break;
  }

  printf("\n");
}
```

But Why you need that infinite loop, your code could be as simple as below:

```
void waitUntill()
{
  printf("\n\nPRESS ENTER TO EXIT !!!\n");
  fflush(stdin);
  getchar();
}
```